# My own database autoincrement - Avoid duplicated keys

Tags: sql-server, jakarta-ee, auto-increment

I have a Java EE Web Application and a SQL Server Database.
I intend to cluster my database later.

Now, I have two tables:
- Users
- Places

But I don't want to use auto id of SQL Server.
I want to generate my own id because of the cluster.

So, I've created a new table `Parameter`. The parameter table has two columns: `TableName` and `LastId`. My parameter table stores the last id. When I add a new user, my method addUser do this:

- Query the last id of the parameter table and increments +1;
- Insert the new User
- Update the last id +1.

It's working. But it's a web application, so how about 1000 people simultaneously? Maybe some of them get the same last id. How can I solve this? I've tried with synchronized, but it's not working.

What do you suggest? Yes, I have to avoid auto-increment.

I know that the user has to wait.

Comment: Well really the only way is to synchronize or use auto increment.

Comment: Can you use a GUID instead for the key?  The DB doesn't always have to be the source of the key.  Be warned that a GUID isn't always as convenient when it comes to referential integrity - you're carrying around a rather large key compared to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic ID may work better in a cluster, but if you want to be database-portable or implement the allocator yourself, the basic approach is to work in an optimistic loop.

I prefer 'Next ID', since it makes the logic cleaner, so I'm going to use that in this example.

1. SELECT the NextID from your allocator table.
2. UPDATE NextID SET NextID=NextID+Increment WHERE NextID=the value you read
3. loop while RowsAffected != 1.

Of course, you'll also use the TableName condition when selecting/ updating to select the appropriate allocator row.

You should also look at allocating in blocks -- Increment=200, say -- and caching them in the appserver. This will give better concurrency & be a lot faster than hitting the DB each time.